# PHP 8.0 FPM run with Valgrind

Tags: php, valgrind, fpm

I want to detect the memory leak using the Valgrind on PHP 8.0 FPM / Apache environment.
I have tried change the DAEMON command in the /etc/init.d/php8.0-fpm but cannot achieve it.
Here is the change for the DAEMON command:

```
export USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0 #Add new for valgrind testing

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process Manager"
NAME=php-fpm8.0
CONFFILE=/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf
# DAEMON=/usr/sbin/$NAME #Removed for valgrind testing
DAEMON="valgrind --leak-check=full --log-file=/var/log/valgrind-log-%p.log /usr/sbin/$NAME"
DAEMON_ARGS="--daemonize --fpm-config $CONFFILE"
```

Not sure anything need to be configured to achieve it.

Comment: Is there anything in your logfile? I expect that demonizing involves forking and that you should use the Valgrind option to trace children. Also consdider setting DAMON to just 'valgrind' and moving all the args to DAEMON_ARGS.

Comment: Thanks @PaulFloyd, I moved all the args to DAEMON_ARGS and had the output, however it doesn't write output during the request, It only write the output after the server is stopped, it is inconvenient but it much better compare to nothing output :), Thanks again.